# AngularJS $resource POST call on Cordova not working on iOS/Android devices but working on browser

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, post

I have the following code to make a "POST" on my end point as follows:

```
var response = $resource(serviceURL, {}, {
        get: {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            },
            transformRequest: function(obj) {
                var str = [];
                for(var p in obj) {
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                }
                return str.join("&");
            }
        }
    });

response.get({
        grant_type : grantType,
        client_id : clientId ,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        username : username,
        password : passwordValue
    }, function(data) {
        alert("Authenticated ...");
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Error");
    });
```

This code for authenticating the users works in the desktop browsers (tested on Chrome) but it is the same code for my Cordova iOS and Android project, but on devices/simulator/emulator, it only executes the fail method.

I have checked the Cordova's config.xml file and it's not a cross domain issues (I have < access orogin="*" /> in the config.xml file).

I have been trying to resolve this for hours but still no luck.

Why is it only failing in devices/emulator/simulator but works in browsers ???

Answer (score 2):

Since cordova-android 4.0.0 you MUST install whitelist plugin. That is, you have to run `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist` and everything should be working fine.

> Whitelist functionality is revamped
>
> You will ***need to add*** the new cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin to continue using a whitelist
>       Setting a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) is now supported and is the recommended way to whitelist (see details in plugin readme).
>       ***Network requests are blocked by default without the plugin, so install this plugin even to allow all requests, and even if you are using CSP.***

Should you need further explanation, please refer to Cordova Android 4.0.0 [release](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/15/cordova-android-4.0.0.html)

Comment: I am using cordova 3.7 and we are not upgrading it to 4.0. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: @jeewan: should work also for cordova 3.6+ but there is nothing about this on the internet. Have you set the config.xml correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved this issues but I am still not sure it will be the best solution as I see some JS error on console saying "Refused to set unsafe header 'Origin'".
 I simply set the header's Origin property with some valid https URL as follows:

```
headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            "Origin": "https://www.google.com"
        }
```

and that worked for me.